# How do I include multiple values in my SOQL where clause?

Tags: soql

All I want to do is return Opportunities where the stage name is not equal to Closed Won or Closed Lost.  I am sure this is simple, but I do not know the correct format.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  Since I am doing this in Dev Console I will use Nihir suggestion this time.   However, both are great answers.  Thanks again!

Comment: For reference, you can use `IN` with literal values, ie `SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Status IN ('Open', 'Under Review')`

Comment: @CraigRowland Don't forget to mark answer as best as it useful for others

Comment: Or in this case: `NOT IN ('Closed Won', 'Closed Lost')`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Totally agree with Rohit's answer for Apex but You can use this soql in developer console :

```
Select Id, Name from Opportunity where stageName != 'Closed Won' AND stageName != 'Closed Lost'
```

Comment: OR isn't correct, because it would still query all opportunities.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for marking, i will take care of it next time :)

Comment: Yeah this would need to be an AND.

Answer (score 6):

You can use NOT IN to filter by multiple values:

```
select id from opportunity where stagename not in ('a','b')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN` keyword. Refer below example:

```
List<String> lst = new List<String>();
lst.add('Closed Won');
lst.add('Win');

List<Opportunity> opList = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity Where StageName NOT IN :lst];
```